# How to get Firebase test lab to not skip my android app for devices of API 30?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-test-lab

I tried using Firebase Test Lab for testing my app. I set my `SdkVersion` in the (app) `build.gradle` as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
```

If I use Firebase Test Lab devices using API 30 to test the app, the app is skipped. Why is this? How to get the API 30 devices to not skip the app test?

Comment: What specific device(s) have you tried testing against?

Have you verified that the app installs correctly on your own device or a local emulator running API 30, and that your tests run correctly in that case?

Comment: I have tried Pixel 2, Virtual, Low-resolution MDPI phone, Virtual, and Pixel 5e. Actually it seems to not skipped on Pixel 5e. I don't have own API 30 device and haven't tried emulator. It seems to not work on Virtual devices at API 30?